# IIs cannot create virtual directory?

Tags: c#, iis, model-view-controller

I am trying to create directory for MVC project. While doing that i am getting this error.

Do we need to give any authorizations for accessing the directory?
[image]

Comment: You probably just need to be running visual studio as Administrator so it has access rights to IIS.

Comment: Following Saqib's suggestion, you do that with mouse right click at your VS icon, and choosing `Run as Administrator`

Comment: Thanks Guys It worked.

Answer (score 0):

issue because your going to create under port 80

try with http://localhost:23444/MVCDemo     this time your using separate port to run the test